# How can I display the results of a dictionary contained in a list to a new web page using flask?

Tags: python, html, list, dictionary, flask

I have a list named **linebline** that contains around 99 lists within it (sublists). Within these sublists are **dictionaries**. I am interested in these dictionaries, as each sublist has a key named 'title' that I want a client/user to be able to query using a URL.

type(linebline) outputs list

type(linebline[0]) outputs dict

So far I have the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app3 = Flask(__name__)

app3.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def grab_title():
    given_title = requests.args.get('title')
    
    book_info = [obj for obj in linebline if obj['title'] == given_title] #.to_html(header="true", table_id="table")
    
    return(book_info)
    #return Response(city_inCom, mimetype = 'application/json')
    
app3.run(host = 'localhost', port = 5003)
```

An example of the query from a client would be:"http://localhost:5003/?title=New%20iPad%20Air%20may%20come%20with%20USB-C%20not%20Lightning%20Port%27"

I am currently getting:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

**I am not sure if I am addressing the 'title' key correctly OR am I not returning the right thing.**

Comment: show us your url, is it something like this: "localhost:5003/?title=YourTitle" ?

Comment: @ClaudioAcioli I added the url under the code, but see below: "http://localhost:5003/?title=New%20iPad%20Air%20may%20come%20with%20USB-C%20not%20Lightning%20Port%27"